# How to get Dependency Properties from Converter in Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.StrokeThickness = 10;
rectangle.Height = 200;
rectangle.Width = 100;

//Self defined propety
Boolean AutoSize = false;
rectangle.DataContext = AutoSize;

//Add binding
Binding bind = new Binding(rectangle.DataContext);
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
bind.Converter = ConvertAutoSize2Height;
bindingList.Add(bind);

canvas.Children.Insert(0, rectangle);

//Value converter
[ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(Double))]
public class ConvertAutoSize2Height : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Boolean autoSize = (Boolean)value;
        if (autoSize)
            return Double.NaN;
        else
            return **<<<I wanna return original height if autosize is false>>>**;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please check the converter, I wanna return the rect's original height if **autosize** is false.

Comment: can't you create a auto property or property that stores the original value of the height.?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Then how to retrieve it in the converter?

Comment: You may be able to achieve this using multibinding and `IMultiValueConverter`. You could then bind both autosize and the original height value and process it in the converter. Take a look at this link for more information about multibinding: http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @LukaszM Thanks alot. I think that will work.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer. Could You accept it? Someone else has posted answer with the same answer as mine just few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a preferred solution, so I'm posting my comment as an answer.

You may be able to achieve this using multibinding and `IMultiValueConverter`. You could then bind both autosize and the original height value and process it in the converter.

Take a look at this link for more information about multibinding: http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html.

Answer (score 0):

U should consider IMultiValueConverter instead of IValueConverter